# How to assign shortcuts to move between KDE Virtual Desktops (Workspaces)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, workspaces

I've got this nifty Virtual Desktops module thing and.. not that its very good... but it has the potential to work, so I thought I'd ask if anyone knows how to assign shortcuts to my virtual desktops.

In Gnome whatever and Unity, you can do it very easily.

Here's a pic of my virtual desktops window:
[image]

All you can do is rename the virtual desktops! Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **System Settings ⇒ Shortcuts ⇒ KWin ⇒ Switch to Desktop 1-20**

KDE configuration system is in an order of magnitude more powerful than what Gnome offers.

Not only you can configure various shortcuts for pretty much anything and everything, you can also assign shortcuts to start any applications or invoke KDE applications exported functions via qdbus, e.g. see:

- [Scripting Konsole — KDE Documentation](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/scripting.html)
- [Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/Introduction — KDE TechBase](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/Introduction)

Comment: @artem-s-tashkinov Where's the jaw drop emoji? You just opened a lot of doors here, thank you! When will Windows get KDE? :D

Comment: @amplesky The entirety of KDE was available for Windows for quite some time but then seeing that very few people used it, KDE developers stopped compiling/offering it. Now only individual applications are offered: https://community.kde.org/Windows